# Adding count(*) to existing mysql query causes unwanted action in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$results_ts = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, title, description, content 
FROM prose WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%' LIMIT 10");

if(isset ($_GET['search_title'])){
while($title_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($results_ts)){
echo $title_arr[id]; //and so on...
```

And that works as I wanted.

but when I try to add `, count(*)` after where `content` is, than `while()` loop echoes only one result, even when `$title_arr[4]`(which stands for count) results in many.

Is it possible to do it this sort of way, or should I be running two separate queries?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get with count(*)? If you simply want a count of the number of results, you can simply use `mysqli_num_rows($results_ts)`

Comment: It isn't meaningless if the table already has a primary key and is sorted, or if you just want a sampling the contents of a table. This looks like searching for an article, in which case ordering results by "best match" would be the desired result, but no column represents how good a match the title is for an arbitrary term.

Comment: What do you want to count ? http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @Strawberry I know, code is not finished, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: @godfathersama If I have LIMIT it will show me correct number only if it's 10 or less.

Comment: @MattRollins What does 'sorted' mean?

Comment: @Strawberry Actually you're right. I was assuming that if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause then you'll always get your data in primary key order - but it's influenced heavily by the order of INSERT and UPDATE queries, and you can't officially rely on that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that in one query.

Think about the result you're expecting: when you do a count(*) query, what you get back is a result with only one row and one value. If you select multiple lines, then what should it do? Inject the count into each row of the data?

From a logical perspective, those are two different things you're looking for.

EDIT: counting the rows in your result after the fact is probably the best option, but that won't work if you're only looking for the first 10 entries, and there's no reason to SELECT the whole table if you don't need all the data. That's why count(*) is fulfilling such a different role.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt Rollins , I did it in two separate queries. I need that limit 10 as well as overall count to divide results into pages of 10 while knowing how many is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function so you can't use it like this. But if all you want is the number of rows this query would have returned you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to get the number of rows that would have been returned if thee was no `LIMIT` clause. You then can get the results by calling `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` after your query is run.